# How are these transparent stairs made?

Tags: building

[image]

What techniques and bricks are used to support the transparent pieces? Can anyone work it out?

Comment: I love this, it looks so good but I wonder how well it holds together.

Comment: They also use transparent 4218's in the windows of one shop in Assembly Square.  The string of 4218's feels very floppy in your hands.  It was a bit weird to get the hang of how they went in, but once you got them in place they were surprisingly stable and resilient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The steps are made of [4218: Garage Roller Door Section without Handle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4218#T=S&C=12&O=%7B%22color%22:%2212%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) pieces in clear transparent.

[image: piece picture]

They are inserted into [2420: Corner 2 x 2 Plate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2420&name=Plate%202%20x%202%20Corner&category=%5BPlate%5D#T=C) pieces.

[image: piece picture]

Answer (score 5):

I *[schmoogle searched](https://www.flickr.com/photos/buildingsblockd/25097393004/)* your picture looking for more reference info, and it says it's named:

"*IMGP7842f - 2016 - Glass Staircase Study With Side Shelves" by Deborah Higdon*.

I couldn't find more shots, but this is how she made it from what I can see.
[image]

Colors are used to help better visualize this masterpiece. Everything that's hidden from camera view on the left side, like the orange 1x1 plates and the red, dark-gray and white corner tiles is just speculation by me.
[image]

Her unorthodox use of the transparent garage pieces as steps are both visually striking and cool, but what makes her piece more grande is when we start reverse engineering it, and become even more pleasantly surprised by what we find.

Taking it all apart, while subtracting the stairs, we realize that the entire left side and right side are reverse studded from the center out?!?  Another bit of the unorthodox.
[image]

We all know the LEGO system doesn't have top/bottom reverse-studded bricks and plates, so we have to ask ourselves, how'd she connect both sides then?

Then we see how she pins her structure together using a combination of modified studded bricks(red and dark green), which are all held together by a 1x8(reddish-brown) tile and a 2x4(nougat colored) plate, which is very nice!
[image]

How she was able to count out the in between plate/brick width of the 1x8 tile is impressive, but what throws me, is BOTH the random use, AND random way she USED the garage pieces for steps.  That's cray-cray.

I haven't tested her design in real life.  Like most of my designs the final glory is the transition from the digital to the real-life. I want to touch it!! So, for these Steps and Cubbyholes, I can't just yet feel the overall structural integrity to reach her vision of final glory.

And finally, I'm super curious about my speculative guess work on her hidden left side. Sometimes when reverse engineering you begin to feel that you somewhat understand the artist's creative side, and can anticipate what their next move would or should be depending on the overall composition and the flow of the design.

I think I'm 100% on the 1x1 orange plates, but that twisty corner tile use, hmmm damn, wish I could see how close I was to the original.
[image]

Animation that shows how the 1x1x1 wall tiles are attached:
[Exploding animation](https://media.giphy.com/media/8FPyK9CWo0GnaxPojX/giphy.gif)

Comment: Great work there Rin - just a quick question though - what are the orange 1x1 tiles attached to? How do they support the grey 1x1x1 corner wall [part:6231] ?

Comment: You can't really embed images in comments, but you can edit your answer to include it - just click the grey "edit" text at the bottom of the answer :)

Comment: Great question my Friend.  Here is a gif with part of that wall disassembled:  
https://media.giphy.com/media/8FPyK9CWo0GnaxPojX/giphy.gif
So, the 1x1 tiles(orange colored) are attached to the middle stud receiving hole of the 2x2 Corner Wall Element (colored white). 
The 1x1x1 Corner Wall Element (light gray) are attached to the middle stud of the 1x2x2 Corner Plate (colored tan).

Comment: From her original shot, I can't see the what piece she used here, but I can see the other pieces around it, and my mind's eye can see a sort of physical world cause and effect her structure would have with a hole left here: When pressure applied the pieces would hinge down and buckle, so to stop that hinge buckling structural weakness, the only piece to lock her structure in place, and still maintaining her design flow, has to be an unseen 1x1 plate.  I'm 100% sure.

Comment: So, in a nut shell, the orange pieces don't support the gray ones at all.  The pictures I provided are angled in a way that gives the illusion of impossible piece attachments.   Ironic how these are 2D screen shots of a 3D environment where the lack of the 3D depth can throw our brains for a loop.  M.C.  Escher in the house.